# c++ WebBrowser block url

Tags: c++, c++builder, twebbrowser

How can I block any URL in a `TWebBrowser` in C++Builder?

I tried this code, but it didn't work the way I expected.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(TObject *ASender, const IDispatch *pDisp,
          const OleVariant &URL, const OleVariant &Flags, const OleVariant &TargetFrameName,
          const OleVariant &PostData, const OleVariant &Headers,
          WordBool &Cancel)
{
    if (URL.operator UnicodeString() == запрещенный_адрес)
        WebBrowser1->Stop();
}
```

Comment: does that code compile? It doesnt look like valid c++ at all.

Comment: yes, he compile

Comment: so how is 'запрещенный_адрес' declared?

Comment: no way. "запрещенный_адрес" its UnicodeString.
example 
if (URL.operator UnicodeString() == "youtube.com")

Comment: your code has no " in it

Comment: can u help me ?

Comment: `запрещенный_адрес` is not a URL, so of course the code doesn't work as expected. What is the **real** value of `Url` that you are interested in blocking?

Answer (score 0):

`запрещенный_адрес` is not a URL.  You have to check for a *complete* URL, including `http:` or `https:` prefix, as needed.

Also, it is not enough to just call `Stop()`, you also need to set the event handler's `Cancel` parameter to true as well.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(TObject *ASender, const IDispatch *pDisp,
    const OleVariant &URL, const OleVariant &Flags, const OleVariant &TargetFrameName,
    const OleVariant &PostData, const OleVariant &Headers,
    WordBool &Cancel)
{
    System::String sUrl = URL;
    if (sUrl == _D("http://the full url here"))
    {
        Cancel = VARIANT_TRUE;
        WebBrowser1->Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me when I use it.

Comment: Put them in a list, and then check if the `URL` is in that list. That is outside the scope of this question.  If you need help figuring it out, post a new question about it.